# PySpark memory usage

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory

I am trying to reading a 0.1-billion-line table using jdbc in pyspark. My computer only has a RAM of 8GB. If I directly read the entire table, there will be an out-of-memory error. Therefore, I choose to split the table and read every 15 million line at a time and append them to a list. Finally, I merge the list to become one dataframe.

The code works but I cannot understand why. Since in both way the entire table is stored in my computer finally, why doesn't the second way report out-of-memory error at last? I guess the reason is that the two methods use different memory in the computer, but I do not know what specific memory they use. Can someone help me explain the memory usage in these two processes and why the second one is successful? Thank you!

I have attached the code below.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7')
findspark.add_packages('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39')
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import datetime

class jdbcReader:
    def readIn(self,url,table,username,password):
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").config("spark.driver.memory", "8g").appName("reader").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
        properties={"user":username, "password":password,"driver":'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'}
        i=0
        df_effset=[]
        while True:
            newTable='(SELECT * FROM '+table+' LIMIT 15000000 OFFSET '+str(15000000*i)+') tmp'
            df_new=spark.read.jdbc(url=url,table=newTable,properties=properties)
            n=df_new.count()
            print('The partial df has '+str(n)+' rows')
            print('Partially finished at '+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            df_effset.append(df_new)
            if n<15000000:
                print('The small df has '+str(n)+' rows!!')
                break
            i+=1
        df_comp = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_effset)
        print('The final size is '+str(df_comp.count())+'rows!!!')

reader1=jdbcReader()
print('Started at '+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
reader1.readIn('xxx','xx','x','x')
print('Finished at '+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no straight answer to your question, it's also impossible to reproduce and prove on my end here. But my suggestion is you can access Spark UI and open the SQL tab on top of the page. You will be able to compare your Spark stages, between reading all in one shot, vs reading every 15M rows.